# How to place tooltip above point in highcharts x-range?

Tags: highcharts

I have created highcharts x-range chart with multiple series in one category. Tooltips are displaying above the middle of the category. I'd like it to display above each x-range point. How can I do it?

I've tried to override tooltip positioner. But the argument point contains values plotX and plotY like it is placed on the middle of y value and I can't calculate its real position.

```
this.tooltipPositioner = function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point){
  return {
    x: point.plotX,
    y: point.plotY
  };
```

};

Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/levra/mh7uj93r/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tooltip.positioner` but instead of the argument point, you can use hovered point object where you will find the correct point plot values. To get hovered point object use `plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver` callback. Check the code and demo posted below:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/xrange.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var hoveredPoint;

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'xrange'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts X-range'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    categories: ['Prototyping', 'Development', 'Testing'],
    reversed: true
  },
  tooltip: {
    positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight) {
      var x = hoveredPoint.shapeArgs.x,
        y = hoveredPoint.shapeArgs.y,
        width = hoveredPoint.shapeArgs.width,
        tooltipOffsetTop = -10;

      return {
        x: x + chart.plotLeft + width / 2 - labelWidth / 2,
        y: y + chart.plotTop - labelHeight + tooltipOffsetTop
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    xrange: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            hoveredPoint = this;
          },
          mouseOut: function() {
            hoveredPoint = null;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Project 1',
      // pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0,
      borderColor: 'gray',
      pointWidth: 20,
      data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
        y: 0,
        partialFill: 0.25
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 5),
        y: 1
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 8),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
        y: 2
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 9),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 19),
        y: 1
      }, {
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 10),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 23),
        y: 2
      }],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Project 2',
      // pointPadding: 0,
      // groupPadding: 0,
      borderColor: 'gray',
      pointWidth: 20,
      data: [{
        x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 23),
        x2: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 2),
        y: 0,
        partialFill: 0.25
      }],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  ]

});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/51gybnew/1/